# AIR mobile runtime memory leak?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-leaks, air, adobe-scout

I have an app developed with AIR 3.7 for iOS (iPad)
The app gets very sluggish after a while, eventually crashes.

I've been -very- careful to pool objects where possible and cleanup / nullify all objects once they're not needed any more.
Profiling the app in Scout returns a pretty stable memory profile (the peaks and the lows translate very well to what's happening on screen)

Simultenously profiling the app using XCode's Instruments, shows me that the apps memory consumption constantly rises up to the point the systems spends more time throwing memory warnings than anything else.

Here are screenshots of both profilers: they show AS3 memory usage being pretty stable. On the app level though, memory consumption keeps rising...

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/608333/AIR_memory_leak.zip

If AS3 is not leaking any memory (according to scout), but the app is (according to Instruments), would I be right assuming there's a memory leak in the AIR-runtime itself?

thanks for your feedback!

bart.

Comment: Are you running a debug .ipa package over USB or network?

Comment: did you packaged the app and installed it or you are using it in debug mode ?

Comment: I compiled a release build, installed it on the iPad. Scout uses the network to send profiling data to the computer, Instruments uses USB.